# Scala Anchored Regex acts as unachored

Tags: regex, scala

So for some reason in Scala 2.11, my anchored regex patterns act as unanchored regex patterns.

```
scala> """something\.com""".r.anchored findFirstIn "app.something.com"
res66: Option[String] = Some(something.com)
scala> """^.something\.com$""".r.anchored findFirstIn "app.something.com"
res65: Option[String] = None
```

I thought the first expression would evaluate as `None` like the second (manually entered anchors) but it does not.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The [`findFirstIn`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#findFirstIn(source:CharSequence):Option[String]) method un-anchors the regex automatically.

You can see that the example code also matches `A` only:

> Example:
>   `"""\w+""".r findFirstIn "A simple example." foreach println // prints "A"`

BTW, once you create a regex like `"pattern".r`, it is anchored by default, but that only matters when you use the regex in a `match` block. Inside the `FindAllIn` or `FindFirstIn`, this type of anchoring is just ignored.

So, to make sure the regex matches the whole string, always add `^` and `$` (or `\A` and `\z`) anchors if you are not sure where you are going to use the regexes.

Comment: I'm a pretty big Scala fan, but this is nuts.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is only supposed to work with match:

```
val reg = "o".r.anchored
"foo" match {
   case reg() => "Yes!"
   case _ => "No!"
 }
```

... returns "No!". 
This doesn't seem very useful, because just `"o".r` is anchored by default anyway. The only use of this I can imagine is if you made some `unanchored`  (by accident? :)), and then want to undo it, or if you just want to match both cases, but s
eparately:

```
val reg = "o".r.unanchored
"foo" match {
   case reg.anchored() => "Anchored!
   case reg() => "Unanchored"
   case _ => "I dunno"
}
```